# Adjoint representation of nilpotent Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be connected nilpotent complex Lie group and consider the adjoint representation $Ad:G\rightarrow GL(\mathfrak g)$. How to show that the eigenvalues of $Ad_g$ are one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all elements $g$ of a nilpotent Lie group $G$ are unipotent (Lie-Kolchin), we have for $g$ that 
$$
(Ad_g-Id)^k=0
$$ 
for some $k$. This is equivalent to saying that all eigenvalues of $Ad_g$ are equal to $1$.